# Getting undefined when accessing array from database

Tags: javascript

I have an array of data base and some other arrays of medicine names.

When I want to access `rivotrilmedi` array I get undefined message in my console 
How I can access this array?

Here is the code

```js
var database = [];

var panadolmedi = ['panadol', 'panadol', 'panadol', 'panadol', 'panadol', 'panadol', 'panadol'];
var favrinemedi = ['Favrine', 'Favrine', 'Favrine', 'Favrine', 'Favrine', 'Favrine', 'Favrine', 'Favrine', 'Favrine', 'Favrine'];
var Rivotrilmedi = ['Rivotril', 'Rivotril', 'Rivotril', 'Rivotril', 'Rivotril', 'Rivotril', 'Rivotril', 'Rivotril', 'Rivotril'];
database.push(panadolmedi);
database.push(favrinemedi);
database.push(Rivotrilmedi);
console.log("this is my medi", database);
for (var i = 0; i < database.length; i++) {
  console.log("this is rivotril", database.Rivotrilmedi);
}


function search() {
  var searchmedi = document.getElementById("n1").value;
  var medilist = " ";

  for (var i = 0; i < database.length; i++) {
    if (database[i] == searchmedi) {
      medilist += '<li>' + database[i] + " ::" + "</li>";
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = medilist;

    } else {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Medicine not found";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="n1" value="Rivotrilmedi" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: You are not pushing a reference to a variable into the array. Look at what you have `console.log(database)` ....

Comment: I created a snippet for you

Comment: ok sir thanks alot <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`database.Rivotrilmedi` **=>** The `dot(.)` notation is used to access the property of the object and not the array element. You need to use index to get it like this -

```js
var database=[];

var panadolmedi=['panadol','panadol','panadol','panadol','panadol','panadol','panadol'];
var favrinemedi=['Favrine','Favrine','Favrine','Favrine','Favrine','Favrine','Favrine','Favrine','Favrine','Favrine'];
var Rivotrilmedi=['Rivotril','Rivotril','Rivotril','Rivotril','Rivotril','Rivotril','Rivotril','Rivotril','Rivotril'];
database.push(panadolmedi);
database.push(favrinemedi);
database.push(Rivotrilmedi);
console.log("this is my medi",database);
console.log("this is rivotril",database[2]);
```

**P.S** If you want to make use of `dot` notation you need to create property like this

```js
  var database={};

    var panadolmedi=['panadol','panadol','panadol','panadol','panadol','panadol','panadol'];
    var favrinemedi=['Favrine','Favrine','Favrine','Favrine','Favrine','Favrine','Favrine','Favrine','Favrine','Favrine'];
    var Rivotrilmedi=['Rivotril','Rivotril','Rivotril','Rivotril','Rivotril','Rivotril','Rivotril','Rivotril','Rivotril'];
    database.panadolmedi = panadolmedi;
    database.favrinemedi = favrinemedi;
    database.Rivotrilmedi = Rivotrilmedi;
    console.log("this is my medi",database);
    console.log("this is rivotril",database.Rivotrilmedi);
```

Comment: @AhmadBilal Glad I helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access to `database.Rivotrilmedi` because the `database` variable is an array and it does not have such property, you have to access it by index:

```js
var database = [];

var panadolmedi = ['panadol', 'panadol', 'panadol', 'panadol', 'panadol', 'panadol', 'panadol'];
var favrinemedi = ['Favrine', 'Favrine', 'Favrine', 'Favrine', 'Favrine', 'Favrine', 'Favrine', 'Favrine', 'Favrine', 'Favrine'];
var Rivotrilmedi = ['Rivotril', 'Rivotril', 'Rivotril', 'Rivotril', 'Rivotril', 'Rivotril', 'Rivotril', 'Rivotril', 'Rivotril'];
database.push(panadolmedi);
database.push(favrinemedi);
database.push(Rivotrilmedi);
console.log("this is my medi", database);
for (var i = 0; i < database.length; i++) {
  console.log("this is rivotril", database[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access Rivotrilmedi thus:

```
database[2]
```

Rivotrilmedi is a variable that is separate from the "database" array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to do this:

```js
var database = {
panadolmedi : ['panadol', 'panadol', 'panadol', 'panadol', 'panadol', 'panadol', 'panadol'],
favrinemedi : ['Favrine', 'Favrine', 'Favrine', 'Favrine', 'Favrine', 'Favrine', 'Favrine', 'Favrine', 'Favrine', 'Favrine'],
Rivotrilmedi : ['Rivotril', 'Rivotril', 'Rivotril', 'Rivotril', 'Rivotril', 'Rivotril', 'Rivotril', 'Rivotril', 'Rivotril']
}
console.log("this is my medi", database);
console.log("this is rivotril", database.Rivotrilmedi);


function search() {
  var searchmedi = document.getElementById("n1").value;
  var db = database[searchmedi];
  var res = document.getElementById("result");
  var lis = [];
  if (db) {
    res.innerHTML='<li>'+db.join("</li><li>")+"</li>";
  } 
  else {
      res.innerHTML = "Medicine not found";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="n1" value="Rivotrilmedi" /><button type="button" onclick="search()">Search</button>
<ul id="result"></ul>
```